# How to combine two date attributes in model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I create a method in the model to combine two `date`'s so that I can iterate through it in `next_user_challenge` and `previous_user_challenge`

**model**

```
def challenge_date
  # deadline + date_started (some challenges have a deadline and others have date_started)
end

def next_user_challenge
  user.challenges.where('challenge_date > ?', challenge_date).order('challenge_date ASC').first
end

def previous_user_challenge
  user.challenges.where('challenge_date < ?', challenge_date).order('challenge_date ASC').last
end
```

**view**

```
<% if @challenge.previous_user_challenge %>
  <%= link_to 'Prev', challenge_path(@challenge.previous_user_challenge), class: "footer-left", style: "color: white; font-style: normal;" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Home', root_url, class: "footer-left" %>
<% end %>

<% if @challenge.next_user_challenge %>
  <%= link_to 'Next', challenge_path(@challenge.next_user_challenge), class: "footer-right" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Home', root_url, class: "footer-right" %>
<% end %>
```

**rails c**

```
# some challenges will just have a deadline
 id: 1,
 name: "Publish a Novel",
 deadline: Sat, 26 Nov 2016,
 date_started: nil,
 days_challenged: nil,
 category: "goal",
 user_id: 117,

# some challenges will just have a date_started
 id: 2,
 name: "Write a Chp",
 deadline: nil,
 date_started: Thu, 20 Oct 2016,
 days_challenged: 10,
 category: "habit",
 user_id: 117,

# and some challenges will have both
 id: 3,
 name: "Run a Mile",
 deadline: Thu, 26 Sep 2016,
 date_started: Thu, 26 Sep 2016, # If challenge has both deadline and date_started then date_started will be the same date as the deadline
 days_challenged: 30,
 category: "habit",
 user_id: 117,
```

Comment: Also provide your controller code. then i will try to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create virtual attributes for those methods in model. So that column will be accessible in view.

```
attr_accessor :challenge_date
attr_accessor :next_user_challenge
attr_accessor :previous_user_challenge
```

Also you can use rails active_record scopes to achieve the same.

```
def challenge_date
   deadline || date_started  
end
```

Comment: `def challenge_date
   deadline || days_challenged
end`

Comment: Get error `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "challenge_date" does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help.

If both are not equal mean the case in which `deadline` or `date_started` is `nil`. Then it will return the one which is not `nil`. When both are present it return one of them as both are equal as mentioned in your use case.

```
def challenge_date
  if deadline != date_started
    [deadline, date_started].reject(&:blank?).join()
  else
    date_started
  end
end
```

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "challenge_date" does not exist` :/